# cassandra-unit for a suite of Java UTs giving intermittent failures if org.gradle.parallel=true

Tags: java, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

I am trying to introduce **cassandra-unit** for a set of UTs running with `org.gradle.parallel=true` for a spring-boot app.

Running all tests is not reliable, though occasionally works.

I guess this is related to issue described at 
https://github.com/jsevellec/cassandra-unit/issues/155 i.e. the first instance is still hanging around when next UT starts and there seems no way to force it to 'quickly' shut down.

My original approach which gives unreliable results is with `org.gradle.parallel=true` i.e.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
@TestExecutionListeners(
  listeners = CassandraUnitTestExecutionListener.class,
  mergeMode = MERGE_WITH_DEFAULTS
)
@CassandraDataSet
@EmbeddedCassandra
public class MyCassandraUnitTest {

  @Test
  public void xxx_xxx() {
  }

}
```

as described at [cassandra-unit/wiki](https://github.com/jsevellec/cassandra-unit/wiki/Spring-for-Cassandra-unit) and [StephanPraetsch github example](https://github.com/StephanPraetsch/spring.boot.cassandra.unit.test/blob/master/src/test/java/com/example/ApplicationTests.java)

As a workaround I tried removing annotations and instead using native API i.e. try keep one running for all test, and with `org.gradle.parallel=false` this appears to be reliable but slows down the overall build. (Still testing to ensure its not coincidence) With this approach

Before unit-class :

```
EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.startEmbeddedCassandra();
```

and After unit-class :

```
EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.cleanEmbeddedCassandra();
```

as described at 
 - https://github.com/jsevellec/cassandra-unit/wiki/How-to-use-it-in-your-code.

The error I get with first approach is timeouts like

```
00:27:31.826 [Test worker] ERROR org.cassandraunit.utils.EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper - Cassandra daemon did not start after 20000 ms. Consider increasing the timeout
```

or else port conflicts like

```
 2017-02-02 19:44:41.741 ERROR 40053 --- [pool-2-thread-1] o.a.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon    : Fatal configuration error

    org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: /127.0.0.1:7010 is in use by another process.  Change listen_address:storage_port in cassandra.yaml to values that do not conflict with other services
        at org.apache.cassandra.net.MessagingService.getServerSockets(MessagingService.java:557)
        at org.apache.cassandra.net.MessagingService.listen(MessagingService.java:501)
        at org.apache.cassandra.net.MessagingService.listen(MessagingService.java:485)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.prepareToJoin(StorageService.java:745)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:648)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:548)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:385)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:601)
        at org.cassandraunit.utils.EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper$1.run(EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.java:129)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

    2017-02-02 19:44:41.745  INFO 40053 --- [       Thread-7] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Closing org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@7ffd8dee: startup date [Thu Feb 02 19:44:17 GMT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
    2017-02-02 19:44:41.972  WARN 40053 --- [iceShutdownHook] org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper        : No local state or state is in silent shutdown, not announcing shutdown
    2017-02-02 19:44:41.972  INFO 40053 --- [iceShutdownHook] o.apache.cassandra.net.MessagingService  : Waiting for messaging service to quiesce
    2017-02-02 19:44:41.982  INFO 40053 --- [iceShutdownHook] org.apache.cassandra.hints.HintsService  : Paused hints dispatch
    2017-02-02 19:44:42.072  INFO 40053 --- [iceShutdownHook] org.apache.cassandra.hints.HintsService  : Paused hints dispatch
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question:
I sacrificed the parallel project build in gradle, i.e. `org.gradle.parallel=false` in my `gradle.properties`

In my tests have:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void before() throws InterruptedException, IOException, TTransportException {
    EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.startEmbeddedCassandra(20000);
}

@AfterClass
public static void after() throws InterruptedException, IOException, TTransportException {
    EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.cleanEmbeddedCassandra();
}
```

The `cleanEmbeddedCassandra()` just wipes the key-spaces but leaves the Cassandra server running.

I would have preferred the cleanup to stop EmbeddedCassandraServer instead of leaving it running until the process quits.

The approach working reliably but not what I wanted perhaps someone will post a better way!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

`EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.startEmbeddedCassandra(EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.CASSANDRA_RNDPORT_YML_FILE);`